# Anonymous types syntax

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I know we can use such syntax

```
var r = new MyType { name = "dd"}
```

Is it possible to have such syntax in any simpler way

```
MyType myType = GetMyType("some method returns instance of mytype"){
       name="myname", 
       otherProp = otherPro, 
       ExecuteMyTypeMethod()
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that what you've shown are *not* anonymous types, which are like this:

```
var r = new { name = "dd" }; // Note the lack of a type name
```

This is *object initializer* syntax - and no, it only works with constructors. I've occasionally found that a pain too, but that's the way it is.

EDIT: A comment suggested using extension methods. You *could* do this:

```
public static T With<T>(this T item, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    action(item);
    return item;
}
```

at which point you could write:

```
MyType myType = GetMyType("some method returns instance of mytype").With(t => {
   t.name="myname";
   t.otherProp = otherPro;
   t.ExecuteMyTypeMethod();
});
```

The *only* benefit of this is that you can still perform the initialization in a single experssion. Usually I'd prefer to just use separate statements.

Comment: Any way using extension method to have such syntax?

Comment: Thanks jon, somewat close except extra With. My preference of this to use when I need reset or re-assign some properties, and execute. I can do in multiple statements, but enclosures are always interesting to me. Does the difference give some performance overhead?

Comment: @hungryMind: The performance difference is unlikely to be significant. The possibility of abusing it and ending up with unreadable code is more severe, IMO :)

Comment: True, I will take note on that :)

Comment: You can add this method to your moreLINQ project